# Use Windows Explorer to list files by pattern?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, file-management

Can Windows Explorer list a subset of the files in a folder?

For example, I want to see all the files with "summary" in the name.  Specifying "H:\Documents*summary*" gives me a 'file not found' error.

This seems like a natural and obvious thing to do.  I'm surprised it doesn't work.

EDIT: I'm on Windows XP.

Comment: What version of windows?

Comment: Are you willing to use 3rd party search options or must it be the one built in to windows?

Comment: Has to be built in to Windows, unfortunately.  I have the common workplace restriction of not being allowed to install software.

Comment: Try the zip version of [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com); it's portable and should work. If you have .Net 3.5 installed then even [AstroGrep](http://sourceforge.net/projects/astrogrep/files/latest/download) might work.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Explorer has a toolbar button labeled "Search". Choose to search "All files and folders", and under the "All or part of the file name" field, you can enter a wildcard if you like.